# Protractor - clicking a link in a list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

Given a todo app that has a list of tasks: Walk the dog, Eat lunch, Go shopping. Each task has a 'complete' link.

Using Protractor, how do I click the complete link for the second task 'Eat lunch'? Preferably I'd like to do this without using indices in my test.

The html structure is like so...

```
<ul class="pending">
    <li ng-repeat="task in tasks">
        {{task.name}}
        <a href='#'>Complete</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This seems like a common situation so surely there has to be a simple solution that I'm overlooking. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
element.all(by.repeater('task in tasks')).
  get(1).
  element(by.linkText('Complete')).
  click()
```

or

```
element.all(by.repeater('task in tasks')).
  get(1).
  $('a').
  click()
```

Comment: is specifying the index 'get(1)' the only way? I suppose I'm more interested in discovering a way to find a 'Complete' button that pairs with a particular task name. This way the test is very declarative. I have a feeling that using explicit indices would be a fragility point in the tests.

Comment: Sure, just do: $('.pending').findElement(by.linkName('Complete'))

Comment: Was the `linkName` selector removed from the Protractor or is a plugin needed?

Comment: I don't see a linkName property either

Comment: Sorry. It is linkText, not linkName